# How to remove unused using statements WITHOUT sorting them?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a built-in way to remove unused `using`s without sorting them, in Visual Studio 2019? I want my unused `using` statements removed but NOT sorted and I don't want to install any Visual Studio extension or Power Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a built-in way. Instead of using '***Remove and Sort Usings***' command on the right click context menu, or its equivalent keyboard shortcut, use '***Quick Actions and Refactorings...***' command, or its equivalent shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, and click on '***Remove Unnecessary Usings***'.